# Não consigo importar todos subniveis do xml com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, importação

Tenho uma função para importar o arquivo xml:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($arquivoxml);
foreach($xml->Imoveis->Imovel AS $itens) {
  $ref=$itens->Id;
  $atributospai = $itens->Atributos;
  foreach ($atributospai->children() as $atr) {
    $atrid = $atr->Id;
    $idsatr.="('".$ref."','".$atrid."'),";
  }
  $idsatr=substr($idsatr,0,-1);
  $sql="INSERT INTO tabelaimovel (ref) VALUES ({$ref})"
  $sqlatr="INSERT INTO tabelaatributo (ref, atributo) VALUES ({$idsatr})"
  $conn->query($sql);
  $conn->query($sqlatr);
}
```

Mas o problema é que não consigo pegar os atributos correspondentes, ele sempre pega só o atributo da primeira referencia, o xml está assim:

```
<Imoveis>
  <Imovel>
    <Id>4181</Id>
    <Atributos>
      <Atributo>
        <Id>23</Id>
      </Atributo>
      <Atributo>
        <Id>42</Id>
      </Atributo>
    </Atributos>
  </Imovel>
  <Imovel>
    <Id>9985</Id>
    <Atributos>
      <Atributo>
        <Id>40</Id>
      </Atributo>
      <Atributo>
        <Id>53</Id>
      </Atributo>
    </Atributos>
  </Imovel>
</Imoveis>
```

Comment: como você está usando dois loops, você irá varrer apenas dois níveis. O ideal seria criar uma função recursiva que varre enquanto houver nós filhos, entende?

Comment: mais ou menos, seria algo tipo criar uma função fora do foreach e chamar ao invés de fazer um foreach dentro do outro?

Comment: Vou fazer um código aqui pro seu caso. Na verdade nem precisa de recursão, veja que você conseguiu fazer o loop em "Imoveis->Imovel", dentro do escopo do Imovel tem mais um loop "Atributos->Atributo", porém não entendi se esse XML é um exemplo real ou só uma demo de estrutura... Pode me explicar?

Comment: é só um demo da estrutura, ele tem outros campos a mais

Comment: Seria possível colocar uma demo com a estrutura usada? Com dados falsos, claro. Porque preciso ver qual a complexidade abordada. Do jeito que está aí, o nome da tag (<Atributo>) seria o nome do atributo e o conteúdo seria o valor, correto? É assim em 100% dos casos? Por isso que peço o exemplo. Vou salvar essa pergunta aqui nos favoritos e mais tarde te respondo.

Comment: Isso, o conteúdo é o valor, preciso apenas desse id, ele é assim em 100% dos casos. o xml inteiro tem muitos campos (uns 50), mas segue tudo o mesmo padrão do nivel id, só o atributo e foto que é igual, tem 2 niveis a mais (atributo e id)

Comment: achei uma solução de gambiarra..rs, depois de executar a query, eu "limpei" a varaivel: $idsatr=''; aí funcionou.

Comment: Leandro, não seria uma gambiarra, limpar variáveis em loop é uma prática normal. De todo modo, teu script não faz varredura em processo de descoberta, ele só funciona especificamente para o atributo "Id" presente em todos os atributos do imóvel. Nesse caso, qualquer campo diferente disso não vai passar, entende? E o principal problema que vejo nessa estrutura é que ela não combina com o SQL, talvez NoSQL. Enfim, se tem garantia de que todos os XML's seguirão esse padrão podemos dizer que o problema está resolvido, certo?